# Data validation remove blank cell that contains formula

Tags: excel, validation

I have a list for data validation that is dynamically pulled from another workbook. Then I want to use data validation on this list -- but even a cell with an empty value cell contains a formula, so the cell is not empty.

In other words, I want to ignore each blank cell, even if it contains a formula if the formula returns an empty value. For example:  " ='[Master.xlsm]2019'!$A1" (for the first cell).

I use this:

```
=OFFSET(REFERANS!$A$1;0;0;COUNTIF(REFERANS!$A:$A;"<>"&"");1)
```

cell a1:a100  ='[Master.xlsm]2019'!$A1 ...

Comment: You should go through [How to ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I choose :

Sub WorkShts()

```
Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    With sh.Range("xxx:yyy")

        .Value = .Value

    End With

Next sh
```

End Sub

then all the problems have gone